# How to use openssh sftp command with a RSA/DSA key specified from the command line

Tags: ssh, sftp, rsa, dsa

The Openssh ssh and scp command provied an `-i` command line option to specify the path to the RSA/DSA key to be used for authentication.

Looking at the sftp man pages I was not able to find a way to specify the RSA/DSA key.

I am looking for a way to do initiate an sftp session that will use a specified RSA/DSA key, and not the ~/.ssh/id_{dsa,rsa} keys.

I tried OpenSSH sftp client on Linux...but it should have the same options on other platforms.

Comment: Please specify which sftp client you are using on which platform.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

One potential option is to use `sftp -oIdentityFile=/path/to/private/keyfile`.  Need more info to say whether that will work for you.  Seems to work under Mac/Linux.

Answer (score 26):

You can simply use the `-i` argument for your sftp or ssh command.

```
sftp -i /path/to/private/keyfile ...
```

If the -i option is not available, you can use the -o option with a syntax like:

```
sftp -oIdentityFile=/path/to/private/keyfile ...
```

Comment: sftp doesn't have a -i option which is presumably why the OP is asking the question.

Comment: works under my Linux hosts but not my Mac laptop where the -i option does not seem to exist.

Comment: My Ubuntu and CentOS hosts don't have a -i switch for sftp

Comment: My CentOS client does: [dmourati@flexo ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 5.6 (Final) [dmourati@flexo ~]$ which ssh
/usr/bin/ssh
[dmourati@flexo ~]$ which sftp
/usr/bin/sftp
[dmourati@flexo ~]$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/sftp
openssh-clients-4.3p2-72.el5
[dmourati@flexo ~]$ man sftp
[dmourati@flexo ~]$ man sftp|head
SFTP(1)                   BSD General Commands Manual                  SFTP(1)

NAME
     sftp - secure file transfer program

SYNOPSIS
     sftp [-1246Cpqrv] [-B buffer_size] [-b batchfile] [-c cipher]
          [-D sftp_server_path] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]

Comment: @dmourati: And mine doesn't
[iain@centos ~]$ which ssh
/usr/bin/ssh
[iain@centos ~]$ which sftp
/usr/bin/sftp
[iain@centos ~]$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/sftp
openssh-clients-4.3p2-72.el5_6.3
[iain@centos ~]$ man sftp|head
SFTP(1)                   BSD General Commands Manual                  SFTP(1)

NAME
     sftp - secure file transfer program

SYNOPSIS
     sftp [-1Cv] [-B buffer_size] [-b batchfile] [-F ssh_config]
          [-o ssh_option] [-P sftp_server_path] [-R num_requests] [-S program]
          [-s subsystem | sftp_server] host
     sftp [[user@]host[:file [file]]]

Comment: looks I need to patch and lose this functionality, bizarre

Answer (score 10):

You can create an alternate config file for the connection and use the `-F` switch to tell ssh to use it. create a config file e.g. ~/.ssh/config.sftp with the contents

```
Host remote.host.tld
User RemoteUserName
IdentityFile /path/to/atlernate/identityfile
```

then call sftp like so

```
sftp -F ~/.ssh/config.sftp remote.host.tld
Connecting to remote.host.tld...
Enter passphrase for key '/path/to/atlernate/identityfile':
sftp>
```

The config above restricts the use of the alternate key (when this config file is used) to user RemoteUserName on  remote.host.tld.

Have a look at the man page for [ssh_confg](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) for the usage of the alternate config file

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! You solution provides a clean alternative to the command line arguments. For now, I prefer to pass all arguments via command line, as I am already using -oPort=ALT_PORT.